# setState inside an async search

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, expo, algolia

I am trying to set a stateful object with results I get from an async search and I'm getting some errors and strange behavior.
I'm using algoliasearch to run this search. Here's the code in pseudo, I can share the full code if needed, but I don't think it's important. The search works just fine and I get results (see comments below)

```
const [results, setResults] = useState(null);
index.search(searchQuery, {...requestOptions})
  .then(({ hits }) => {
    fetchedResultsArray = hits?.map((result) => {
      ...
      return {...}
    }
    // console.log("fetchedResultsArray", fetchedResultsArray)
    setResults(fetchedResultsArray)
  ).catch
```

It causing the app to act funny, get stuck, sometimes crash. Sometimes I get this (very long) error: `Warning: Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code: {"1531":{"module":"NativeAnimatedModule","method":"startAnimatingNode"}...`
When I comment `setResults(fetchedResultsArray)`  and uncomment the console log before it, it prints the results and the app acts normal. Reverting back to `setResults(fetchedResultsArray)` and things go wrong again. I am doing something wrong/illegal, but what?
Another important thing to mention is that I'm using Expo SDK 41 beta 2.

**UPDATE**

Patrick, you pointed out what I am doing wrong. Let me show you in a little more depth what I do in my `SearchScreen`, again abbreviated:

```
const SearchScreen = () => {
  // I get the initSearch function from a custom hook and you already see above what the function is.
  const [
    initSearch,
    ...
  ] = useSearch();

  // Then I fire the search when the screen loaded
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (region) {
      initSearch({ searchQuery, region, filterOptions, priceOptions });
    }
  }, [filterOptions, initSearch, priceOptions, region, searchQuery]);
  ...
```

my custom hook is something like this:

```
export function useSearch() {
  const [readyToAnimateAfterSearch, setReadyToAnimateAfterSearch] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [results, setResults] = useState<Result[] | null>(null);

  const setAlert = useStore(useCallback((state) => state.setAlert, []));
  const setProgressBarVisible = useStore(useCallback((state) => state.setProgressBarVisible, []));

  const [radius, setRadius] = useState<number>(0);
  const initSearch = useCallback(
    async ({ searchQuery, region, filterOptions, priceOptions, loadMore = false }) => {
      ...
    },
    [results, setResults, setAlert, setProgressBarVisible]
  );
  return [
    initSearch,
    results,
    setResults,
    radius,
    readyToAnimateAfterSearch,
    setReadyToAnimateAfterSearch,
  ] as const;
```

Could you please suggest an alternative way to run this as an answer. No need to go into details, just so I get the flow of how you would handle this. Thank you!

Comment: Side effects should never be written directly in the body of a function component. You're triggering a search every time the component re-renders, which is every time you're calling `setResults()` (and more) from your asynchronous callback in this case.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ok, I see what you mean. I updated my question. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

My main issue was me using `results` inside the `initSearch` function, instead of using a stateUpdater function and removing `results` from the deps array.